# calculating a date and returning the week number depending on the start date in php?

Tags: php

im trying to create a function that takes a `$start_date` as parameter and it should calculate which week number we are in i.e

for instance $start_date equals `2012-08-16`

```
private function get_week_number($start_date){
        // get current date
        // caluculate the difference between start_date and current_date
        // determine which week we are in 1, 2 or 3
        // return $week 
    }
```

how can i implement this in php? thanks

Comment: i think its just a matter of calculating how many 7 seven days between the current date and the start date?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_week_number($start_date){
    $date = date('U', strtotime($start_date));
    $now = date('U');
    return ceil(($now-$date)/60/60/24/7);
}

echo get_week_number('2012-08-16');
```

Comment: Using date('W') will return the week number of the *year* not the month.

Comment: ups, I thought he was asking for year week :)

Comment: and isn't week 1 from `2012-08-16`?

Comment: 16 days into a month can't be the first week?

Comment: No, he asked in what week we are after a specific date, not current month

Comment: You might be right, I am reading the OP as asking which week of the month we are in. I am +1'ing because based on your understanding of the question, it is right - and I may well be understanding it wrong :)

Comment: can you exlpain the last line why did you decide to divide by 60 twice and then 24 then 7, i dont get that, i know that ceil rounds up the highest integar, thanks :)

Comment: 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 7 days = 1 week. I have converted NOW and DATE Inserted to Unix timestamps, extracted Date from Now, it resulted in a number of seconds and divided those seconds by 1 week.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is merely [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php).

Comment: If you could you expand this further with an example and not just a link (albeit to the correct function) you will get a +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private function get_week_number($start_date){
    return date('W') - date('W', strtotime($start_date)); 
}
```

Comment: This is also wrong. `date('W')` returns the week number, not the week of the month.

Comment: OP requires the no. of weeks between $start_date and current day. Hence it will produce the required output.

Comment: @futuregeek But there are in the 2nd week from 14 Aug to 22 Aug.